# Motivation for match expression syntax

Tags: scala, syntax, pattern-matching

The syntax for match expressions is pretty nice:

```
expr match {
    case Test(l1) => ...
    ...
}
```

But it's driving me nuts that I don't understand the motivation to why this this syntax is used instead of `match (expr) ...`, like branching statements in a decent C descendant!

I see no reasonably explanation for this. And I don't find the answer neither in Programming in Scala, the Scala web site, [in this paper](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~emir/written/MatchingObjectsWithPatterns-TR.pdf), [this thesis](http://library.epfl.ch/en/theses/?nr=3899), here on SO nor on the rest of the web.

It's not that it's anything wrong with it, just that it's a complete mystery. And when `match` work in this way, why not `if` and `for` also?

Does anybody know? I don't think I can stand using the language any longer without finding this out. I think about it all the time. I can hardly sleep at night.

Comment: Considering that it's possible to write a *custom* match-like method (as `{ case ..}` creates a PartialFunction) then `expr match { .. }` can be viewed as syntax Scala supports for "dotless method invocation" for `expr.match { .. }` then it would be consistent with a custom method, `expr.myMatch { .. }` -> `expr myMatch { .. }`. It also keeps consistency with `catch`.

Comment: Hm. Right. That seems like one valid theory. The Scala folks are very into making it easy to integrate user defined expressions so that they look native. Thanks you for your thoughts on the subject! But the question remains: Why only for `match`?

Comment: I *think* I've seen this syntax choice discussed before (in a wite paper co-authored my Martin?), but I can't recall where. On the other hand, Scala syntax is sometimes what I'd consider "overly flexible".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To take a similar bit of Scala syntax, guards in pattern matching cases don't require parentheses around their conditional expressions—e.g., the following:

```
case i if i % 2 == 0 => i / 2
```

Is just as valid as this:

```
case i if (i % 2 == 0) => i / 2
```

Sticking to the C-family style would mean requiring the latter form, even though the parentheses aren't necessary for disambiguation. The Scala language designers decided that reducing line noise trumped maintaining the family resemblance in this case.

I'd guess that a similar motivation is at work in the `match` syntax, and to my eye `match (expr) { ... }` does indeed look pretty awful (and misleading) compared to `expr match { ... }`.

Also, just this afternoon I refactored someone else's `x match { ... }` on an `Option` to `x map { ... }` instead. `match` as an infix operator makes the similarity between these two expressions clear.

On the issue of why `match` isn't just a method, here's a five year-old question from David Pollak on [the `scala-debate` mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.debate/197):

> Why is 'match' a language level construct rather than a method on Any?

And [Martin Odersky's answer](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.debate/199):

> It used to be that way in Scala 1. I am no longer sure why we changed.
>   syntax highlighting? error reporting? not sure. I don't think it
>   matters much either way, though.

I'm with Martin on this one.

Note that there are a couple of practical differences (apart from the simple "dot or not" question). For example, this doesn't compile:

```
def foo[A, B](f: PartialFunction[A, B])(a: A) = a match f
```

If `match` were still a method on `Any`, requiring a literal bunch of cases would be a rather strange requirement.

Comment: Exchanging `expr match { ... }` for `expr map { ... }` is an interesting note. I come across this sometimes, too. `expr foreach { ... }` as well.

Comment: Sadly, the link to Martin Odersky's answer is now broken.