# Why was match in Scala implemented as a keyword rather than as a method?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-macros

What got me thinking was why the following

```
<something> match { ... }
```

could not be rewritten as

```
<something>.match({ ... })  # error: identifier expected but 'match' found.
```

I guess it's because it wouldn't have been possible to implement `match` as a regular method, but I'm not sure. Or perhaps it was for performance reasons.

Also, now that macros are available, would `match` be possible to be implemented using a macro instead? (not that it should be done, but just hypothetically)

EDIT: This seems related to e.g. [What is scala's experimental virtual pattern matcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533826/what-is-scalas-experimental-virtual-pattern-matcher); thanks to @om-nom-nom for pointing it out.

Comment: Is there any benefit of making match implemented via macros? Especially given that there is a *virtualized pattern matching*?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I don't know—I asked the question for learning/understanding purposes; but who knows—removing special cases sometimes has initially non-obvious benefits. Also, I didn't know anything about *virtualized pattern matching* so far but checking it out now.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: based on what I've just learned from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533826/what-is-scalas-experimental-virtual-pattern-matcher, I would answer "yes" to the second part of your question.

Comment: See [my answer to this almost identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17799605/334519).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Motivation for match expression syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799024/motivation-for-match-expression-syntax)

Comment: @TravisBrown: how is that a duplicate of that question? the other question doesn't ask about the method vs keyword separation, does it? I can see that in your answer, you mention the possibility of `match` being a method of `Any`, but the question does not.

Comment: @TravisBrown: not sure why you're not replying, but my point is that even though it's likely that your answer contains a duplicate of what would/could be an answer to this one, it seems to me the question itself is not.

Comment: I wasn't not-replying for any particular reason, and didn't mean to offend (I'm not the downvoter). I still think the questions are close (although I'll admit not "almost identical"), and I don't think "why" questions about language design are a particularly good fit for this site, anyway—one of the Scala mailing lists would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having it as a keyword, it need not be associated to type Any, so the compiler is free to infer the input type of the (partial) function. If it was a method of Any it would take a Function[A, B] as argument.

The practical implications are that

```
3 match { case "foo" => "bar" }
```

causes the **compile error** 'type mismatch'

but a (type paramerterless) matchMethod;

```
3.matchMethod { case "foo" => "bar" }
```

causes the **runtime exception** 'scala.MatchError'

then even if we verbosely explicitly paramerterized the types we still wouldn't get a compile error for the following situation:

```
"foo".matchMethod[Int, String] { case 3 => "bar" }
```

rather we would get the **runtime exception** 'java.lang.ClassCastException' as under the hood we would have to use .asInstanceOf.

The other bonus is syntax highlighting, matchs jump out in code more than yet another method, which I believe it deserves as pattern matching is such a key part of Scala it deserves special attention.

ADDITION: For similar reasons you want try catch to be a keyword construct rather than a function that takes two functions as parameters.  match is then consistent with catch, which is also consistent with Java.

*This answer is an expansion on Martin Odersky's, which was first pointed out by TravisBrown*

Comment: I disagree with the stated limit of the type inference. It is trivial to create an implicit class that allows type-safe pattern matching:

`implicit class MatchOps[A](private val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def m1[B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): B =
    pf.applyOrElse(a, throw new MatchError(a))
  
  def m2[B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): Option[B] = 
    pf.lift.apply(a)
}`

Here m1 acts as the current `match` keyword while m2 would be akin to a `matchOption`

Answer (score 2):

samthebest's answer is probably the real reason (I don't know, that's not something I'm familiar with), but there is another way of looking at it that relates to functional programming more generally.

It is well known that matches in functional programming can be done without any special languages features ([Church Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding))

```
trait List[+T] {
    def mmatch[R](nil: => R, cons: (T, List[T]) => R): R
}
object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
    def mmatch[R](nil: => R, cons: (Nothing, List[Nothing]) => R) = nil
}
class Cons[+T](head: T, tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
    def mmatch[R](nil: => R, cons: (T, List[T]) => R) = cons(head, tail)
}

def sum(l: List[Int]): Int = l mmatch (
    nil = 0,
    cons = (x, xs) => x + sum(xs)
)

val list = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, Nil))

println(sum(list))
```

In this interpretation, when you write

```
sealed trait List[+T]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+T](head: T, tail: List[T]) extends List[T]
```

the word `sealed` is the value/term that provides the `match` function.

So one way of reading your question is, why not just do that? Why not build matches out of other basic language features rather than providing a syntactic match?

The reason is that syntactic `match` provides some syntactic sugar that people like:

- Overlapping match functions:

  ```
  sealed trait A
  sealed trait B
  case object X extends A
  case object Y extends A with B
  case object Z extends B
  ```
- Nested match functions:

  ```
  (1 :: 2 :: Nil) match {
      case x :: y :: Nil => ???
  }
  ```

  This is very awkward to write without syntactic sugar. You can do it; I tried out exploring the possibility when [trying to implement monadic extractors](https://github.com/ellbur/scala-monadic-match); but it sure is less pretty.
- Automatic selection of open vs closed match functions.

  That is, extractors in Scala are like open match functions because any may fail by returning `None`; the compiler won't check for a complete `match` but you can chain as many together as you like and Scala selects the first one. On the other hand, `sealed` traits provide closed match functions with the benefit of completeness checking. These would need to be provided by separate functions, but Scala lets you use the same `match` syntax for both.

Personally I have a suspicion that the above requirements do not, ultimately, necessitate special syntactic support for matches. I suspect that other, more general language features can end up providing the same benefit, particularly in the area of nested matches. However, for the time being it simply makes more sense to hit the problem directly with a special `match` syntax.